# Can a custom class be used in the Conditions of a rule / policies?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, business-rules, biztalk-rule-engine

I am getting started with Biztalk 2010 for the first time.

I looked at this article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/BRE.aspx) for making a custom action to fire against a condition, but it seems that properties are being used in actions, not conditions. Can an action reference a .NET method which accepts non-primitive types as parameters (e.g. custom classes etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BizTalk Rules Engine can deal with several types of facts, including plain-old CLR objects, both in condition evaluation as well as actions.

In order to test you policies, through, you will need to create a [custom Fact Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995541%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) for the specific .Net classes you want to use.

When using .NET objects as facts, please, pay close attention to [correctly implementing object identity](http://geekswithblogs.net/cyoung/articles/110852.aspx) with the help of the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Comment: Thanks! So, when I derive from IFacCreator, I need to pass in my type here: myFacts.SetValue(new MySampleBusinessObject(),0); How would I say "if (type.x == 5) in the condition"?

Comment: Using custom fact creator is only useful to test policies that interact with instances a custom .NET class in the Business Rules Composer. In orchestrations, you only have to supply valid instances of said custom class. You custom class should have a get Property that you can use in your condition like any other object.